# HTTP Request from a Google's cloud function

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to integrate my android app with Google's Assistant.

If the Agent sends me a particular category, I make a network call to my own server.

```
if (factCategory === FACT_TYPE.BANDWIDTH) {
   var request = require('request');
   request({
     uri : 'https://www.example.com?query',
     method: "GET",
     timeout: 10000
   }, function(error, response, body) {
            //my code
   }
});
```

But I am not getting any response for this condition in the assistant app. I'm not sure if the http request hits the url even.

Can someone help me figuring out what goes wrong exactly.

Comment: Can you post more code? How are you handling the HTTPS request that is being sent to your webhook? How is "factCategory" being set? You mention an Android app, but you're not clear about how that is working with the server. We need a lot more information to be able to help.

Comment: Its just the FactsAboutGoogle project given in the developer guide. I have just added added one more category "Bandwidth". I have verified that this 'if' validates to true when the user says bandwidth. But I'm not sure if the request(); is called.

Comment: Feel free to update your question with as much info as you can.

Comment: Have you put anything in to log that the callback is being called?

Comment: What does your code look like that returns something to the user? (And where is it in the code?)